# Dummy Output - Pulseaudio card profiles not loaded - Help!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hda-intel

My sound system is replaced by a 'Dummy output'. The issue comes and goes, I really don't know how to address it.
The problem persists even after reinstalling ubuntu and running a live image.

I've tried reloading Pulseaudio and Alsa, reinstalling packets, editing the alsa-base.conf, adding my user to the audio group. No help.

- I noticed that when the problem occurs, analog profiles are not loaded from pulseaudio, as seen in the pacmd list-cards output

For reference, I've found a dump of a correct execution of the pulseaudio deamon https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-not-working-after-upgrading-from-alsa-to-pulse-audio/81013/4

```
$ inxi -SA
System:
  Host: frejol-UX330UAK Kernel: 5.11.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-43-generic
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-usb:0                   
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
       vendor: 04081-0009610016301027633
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 0.01
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:129 memory:ef128000-ef12bfff memory:ef100000-ef10ffff
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 1 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1043:1520]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 20
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9d71"
        device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

```
$ pacmd dump
### Configuration dump generated at Mon Jan  3 07:40:42 2022

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-console-kit
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-role-cork
load-module module-snap-policy
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-x11-publish display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
load-module module-x11-cork-request display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
load-module module-x11-xsmp display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority session_manager=local/frejol-UX330UAK:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1985,unix/frejol-UX330UAK:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1985
load-module module-cli-protocol-unix

set-sink-volume auto_null 0x10000
set-sink-mute auto_null no
suspend-sink auto_null no

set-source-volume auto_null.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute auto_null.monitor no
suspend-source auto_null.monitor no

set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 off

set-default-sink auto_null
set-default-source auto_null.monitor

### EOF
```

```
$ lsmod | grep snd

snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_soc_skl           159744  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         147456  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_core          286720  3 soundwire_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm               114688  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is d56524bdbbea43738a0de327498c40a0.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/frejol/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/frejol/.config/pulse/d56524bdbbea43738a0de327498c40a0-device-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-stream-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/frejol/.config/pulse/d56524bdbbea43738a0de327498c40a0-stream-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/frejol/.config/pulse/d56524bdbbea43738a0de327498c40a0-card-database'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-connect" (index: #5; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import hw:0 (empty configuration)
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import HDA Intel PCH (empty configuration)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: UCM not available for card HDA Intel PCH
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround21:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dca:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dca:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:0'
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,1
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,1: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,2
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,2: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,3
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,3: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,4
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,4: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D11p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,5: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D11p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,5: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D11p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,5: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,5
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,5: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D12p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,6: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D12p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,6: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D12p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,6: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,6
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,6: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D13p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,7: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D13p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,7: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D13p' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:0,7: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM dcahdmi:0,7
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device dcahdmi:0,7: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:0: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Restoring port latency offsets for card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3: active_profile: off
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: Created 0 "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3"
I: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: ELD device found for port hdmi-output-0 (3).
I: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: ELD device found for port hdmi-output-1 (7).
I: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: ELD device found for port hdmi-output-2 (8).
I: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: ELD device found for port hdmi-output-3 (9).
I: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: ELD device found for port hdmi-output-4 (10).
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #7; argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"").
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3) module loaded.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 1 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #6; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #8; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: Restoring default sink 'auto_null'.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: configured_default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module-default-device-restore.c: No previous default source setting, ignoring.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #9; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for sink auto_null: front-left: 16185 /  25%,   front-right: 16185 /  25%
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
I: [null-sink] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #11; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #10; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #12; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #13; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-console-kit" (index: #14; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] client.c: Created 0 "Login Session 2"
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: exit_idle_time: 20 -> 0
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #16; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-role-cork" (index: #17; argument: "").
I: [snapd-glib] module-snap-policy.c: Starting GLib main loop
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-snap-policy" (index: #18; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #19; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #20; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
```

```
$ sudo killall timidity
timidity: no process found
```

Comment: Did you have any success?